# call_user_func_array vs ReflectionMethod

Tags: php

I was wondering about what the best practices are when it comes to call a class method using the above functions to fill up a method call dynamically using an array!

What advantages and disadvantages do I have? I mean, it seems the RefelectionMethod + invokeArgs option is up to 40% faster than the call_user_funcion in certain conditions… but do I miss something?

thanks.

As requested i will add a little benchmark of my scenario where i needed refereces to be passed... i know its a very specific case and that this is not stricly related to the question above!

```
class foo { public function bar(&$a, &$b, &$c) { /* */ } }
$t1 = microtime(true);
$arr = array(1,2,3);
$foo = new foo;
$rfl = new ReflectionMethod('foo', 'bar');
for ($i=0; $i < 10000; ++$i)
{   
    $rfl->invokeArgs($foo, $arr);   
}

$t2 = microtime(true);
echo sprintf("\nElapsed reflectionmethod  : %f", $t2 - $t1);
$t1 = microtime(true);
$arr = array(1,2,3);
$foo = new foo;

for ($i=0; $i < 10000; ++$i)
{
    foreach( $arr as $k => $v ) $ref[$k] = &$arr[$k];       
    call_user_func_array( array($foo, 'bar'), $arr);
}

$t2 = microtime(true);
echo sprintf("\nElapsed calluserfuncarray : %f", $t2 - $t1);
```

the result

```
Elapsed reflectionmethod  : 0.025099
Elapsed calluserfuncarray : 0.051189
```

**I really would just like to know when its better to use one versus the other, and why! its not strictly related to speed though!**

Comment: "I mean, it seems the RefelectionMethod + invokeArgs option is up to 40% faster than the call_user_funcion" -- could you please add a test case for that?

Comment: @zerkms I've done just a very few and specific tests on this but i will eventually add them to the end of the question :)

Comment: You know, you could just adjust the line spacing in your IDE...

Comment: @phant0m its not the ide, its me. i like it more when its explosed like that! thanks for fixing formatting btw it saves some space :)

Comment: Yes, but some IDEs can make lines taller so you get the effect of having multiple lines without actually having any physically (or virtually, I should say) ;)

Comment: @phant0m that would be cool though! mine doesnt, too bad! xD

Answer (score 5):

Not sure where you got your test results but `RefelectionMethod + invokeArgs option is up to 40% faster than the call_user_funcion` seems far fetched it can only be possible with single instance multiple invoke

Simple Benchmark

```
set_time_limit(0);
echo "<pre>";
class Foo {

    public function bar($arg1, $arg2) {
    }
}

$globalRefection = new ReflectionMethod('Foo', 'bar');
$globalFoo = new Foo();

// Using call_user_func_array
function m1($args) {
    $foo = new Foo();
    call_user_func_array(array($foo,"bar"), $args);
}

// Using ReflectionMethod:invoke
function m2($args) {
    $foo = new ReflectionMethod('Foo', 'bar');
    $foo->invoke(new Foo(), $args[0], $args[1]);
}

// Using ReflectionMethod:invokeArgs
function m3($args) {
    $foo = new ReflectionMethod('Foo', 'bar');
    $foo->invokeArgs(new Foo(), $args);
}

// Using Global Reflection
function m4($args) {
    global $globalRefection;
    $globalRefection->invokeArgs(new Foo(), $args);
}

// Using Global Reflection + Glbal foo
function m5($args) {
    global $globalRefection, $globalFoo;
    $globalRefection->invokeArgs($globalFoo, $args);
}

$result = array('m1' => 0,'m2' => 0,'m3' => 0,'m4' => 0,'m5' => 0);
$args = array("arg1","arg2");

for($i = 0; $i < 10000; ++ $i) {
    foreach ( array_keys($result) as $key ) {
        $alpha = microtime(true);
        $key($args);
        $result[$key] += microtime(true) - $alpha;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
echo "Single Run\n";
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output

```
Single Run
Array
(
    [m1] => 0.018314599990845   <----- call_user_func_array 
    [m2] => 0.024132013320923   <----- ReflectionMethod:invoke
    [m3] => 0.021934270858765   <----- ReflectionMethod:invokeArgs
    [m4] => 0.012894868850708   <----- Global Relection
    [m5] => 0.01132345199585    <----- Global Reflection + Global Foo
)
```

[See Live Action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sBaFAO)